# Appropriate layer for a DocumentPaginator

Tags: wpf, mvvm, printing, user-controls, service-layer

I created a generic Paginator that leverages some Attributes to paginate an IEnumerable of any given type.

At first I placed it in my services project, but now I'm not sure anymore, since afaik every service has to expose an interface, and in this case the DocumentPaginator doesn't. Also, the paginator exposes a GetPage method that returns a DocumentPage, that is actually a View object. Am I wrong? If not, then it must be placed in the Views project.

So I thought an idea may be to create a UserControl (View) or a CustomControl, something like the PrintDialog, that contains all the "preview and print" logic.

What do you think?

Thank you guys!